# How can I convert a MSBuild VS C++ shared library project from targeting Windows x64 to Android ARM64?

Tags: visual-studio

I don't want to use CMake. Only MSBuild.
Any directional help at all, would be appreciated.

Bonus: Is there a way to do this without manually editing the .vcxproj file?

I have the Android NDK & SDK installed and working to generate .so files in QtCreator. In VS, I've tried changing the "target platform" in a project's settings, but that only seems to change the CPU arch, not the OS target.

Comment: After hours of scouring the web for documentation covering visual studio + ndk development without CMake, it seems that this feature is abandonware. CMake is microsoft's recommended system for cross platform builds with visual studio (source: https://youtu.be/yImev317_Ns?t=80)